# Unity breaks Visual Studio options

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015

I have installed Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition via Unity's installer and some of the options windows look like this:

[image: Visual Studio options look broken]

Nothing fixes it; uninstalling-installing, formatting or installing on different machines. Apparently no one complains about this issue because there seems to be nothing on search results, but I'm 100% sure that everyone is experiencing this issue. When you open Visual Studio on its own, problem goes away, it works like it should. However, making Unity open Visual Studio causes it. I assume that this is caused by Unity forcing Visual Studio to load a plugin (probably Visual Studio Tools for Unity) which is actually incompatible with almost everything in Visual Studio.

Is there a solution to this problem? It drives me crazy and I don't want to use MonoDevelop.

Comment: Unfortunetly I have no idea about htis issue, but why you dont want to use MonoDevelop? I know it is not perfect, but is quite usefull tool.

Comment: @JerrySwitalski That's the problem: it is not perfect, only quite useful. I do use MonoDevelop on my Mac, but coding on MonoDevelop feels like trying to write an essay with my left foot: it is just unnatural, and lacks of very important features such as "opposable thumb".

Comment: you made my day with this "left foot" :) but I agreee, when you try VS, IDEs like MonoDevelop seams like crap.

Comment: the "Unity, Mac user -> PC, monodevelop" issue is definitely a huge problem.  If I was a billionaire I'd pay the TextWrangler guys to make a PC version  :/